# Use select() with a non-file-descriptor-based input

Tags: c++, c, select

To my knowledge, the `select()` function in C can only wait for file descriptors to become active (i.e. for reading them to not block.)

This is useful for a command-line messaging application since everything will be either a socket file descriptor, or stdin.

However, what if I want to incorporate this with a GUI application (for example, one written in Gtk?)

I assume there's no way to tell `select()` to wait for a button to be pressed, right? So will I have to use multithreading?

Comment: In X11 this is actually possible because the whole API runs over a socket.

Comment: In a GUI application you should be responding to messages, not using select.

Comment: @NeilButterworth for most things, sure

Comment: Perhaps you should provide a concrete example of what you are trying to  do.

Comment: @NeilButterworth i'm trying to wait for clients on sockets to send a message, as well as waiting for the server GUI user to type a message and press send
anyway, i've got the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to incorporate non-fd activity into a `select`-based event loop (or other fd-related alternatives like `epoll`), you can do that by using a pipe. The action triggered by the event (such as a button press) writes a description of the event into the pipe, and the `select` mask includes the read end of the pipe, so it will be notified of the data availability.

If the events and the handlers are in the same process, it's not necessary to fully serialise the event description, since some other mechanism could be used (a in-memory queue of events, or some such). However, since most events can be easily and efficiently described in a few bytes, serialising the event provides an easily scalable architecture.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. Do you know of anywhere I can read more about how to do this? Or could you provide a code example?

Comment: @JacobGarby: I don't think I know enough about Gtk to provide a relevant code example but the idea is simple enough. The application-dependent part is configuring the button to (synchronously, if possible) call a user-supplied function. That function should collect the relevant details (in this case, the identifier of the button and the type of action, press or release) and create a little message which can be written to a pipe. You could even use a text message (eg. "(PRESS:id27)"); just make sure that it is easily-parsed and unambiguously-terminated....

Comment: ... Don't use printf, because the message must be written atomically and printf doesn't guarantee that it will just do one write. sprintf to a buffer and write the buffer to the pipe. Other than that, it's straightforward.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading this conversation right, but maybe [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) helps.  Gets you a couple of `fd`s anyway, sounds like a good place to start.